# How to resolve colliding protocol names in Swift project

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I've got a Swift project that leverages multiple cocoapods / 3rd party libraries. For sake of simplicity, let's say that both library A and library B have a protocol called `MyProtocol`.

In my app, I'd like to conform to library A's `MyProtocol`, but Xcode keeps saying "`MyProtocol` is ambiguous for type lookup in this context." I assume that's because there are two flavors of `MyProtocol`, and it can't tell which one I'm referring to.

Is there a way around this error or a way to tell Xcode which version of the protocol I'm trying to implment? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the package name before the protocol: `A.MyProtocol` or `B.MyProtocol`.

Comment: Thanks, Rob! I thought that might be the solution as well, but that resulted in a different error: "`MyProtocol` is not a member type of class `FrameworkA.FrameworkA`". Might it be possible that the framework itself is busted?

Comment: Seems like the issue might be explained here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/123253

Comment: Marking the answer as accepted since it answers the question I asked .. even though the underlying problem still exists

Comment: I was able to resolve my follow-up question. The framework was indeed busted as a result of the Swift bug described in the link above. I worked with the framework provider to have them change the name of the module, which removed the `FrameworkA.FrameworkA` error and allowed me to refer to it explicitly once again.

Comment: I just got the "FrameworkA.FrameworkA" error when trying to use a xcframework (via Cocoapods) that has a Swift class. Yes, the framework name and class name are the same, which is not uncommon! Fortunately, I'm the framework developer as well, so now I need to decide which name to change...